# How to access TextView attributes in Adapter class from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, landscape

I am having a Fragment class which has -

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list, container, false);

        // Set the adapter
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);
        mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Set OnItemClickListener so we can be notified on item clicks
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        //Save TextView attributes here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //Restore them here   
        }
    }
```

I have `MyAdapter` class which has the TextView `'time'`-

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        Child child = children.createStopFromCursor(cursor);

                    viewHolder.time.setText(strText);
                    viewHolder.time.setTextColor(0xff000000);
                    viewHolder.time.setTextSize(17);
                    viewHolder.time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.time.setBackgroundColor(nColor);
                    viewHolder.time.setPadding(25,25,25,25);
                    view.invalidate();
        }
    }
```

My question is I want to save the various attributes of the textview `time` like text,color,padding etc in `onSaveInstanceState()` so that when my phone config changes, I can use it `onCreate()`. How do I achieve this?

Comment: use `setRetainInstance(true);` in `onCreate()` of fragment. So the fragment wont be destroyed when config changes.

Comment: I tried but its not working :(

Comment: It will work. When the activity recreates, find this fragment by id or tag and add this fragment in activity.

Comment: Could you please give me an example .. It would help me

Comment: in OnCreate() of activity, `yourFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
        if (yourFragment == null) {
            yourFragment = new YourFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(yourFragment,TAG).commit();
        }`

Comment: Activity has nothing to do here... Its the fragment class and adapter class responsible for this

Comment: When Fragment is not recreated, when activity recreates, you have to just replace your old fragment in recreated activity, so the states of fragment wont be lost.

Comment: I have fragment being recreated..I have onPause and onResume veing called. I verified with logs... After fragment is recreated in onCreate() and then onResume(), I call setRetainInstance(true) which doesnt work